# How to link vanilla js asset in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to link my vanilla js scripts which is in assets folder as follows:-

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <Header />
   </div>
</template>
<script>
 import Header from './components/Header.vue'
 export default {
   name: 'app',
   components: {
      Header
   },
   mounted(){
      let initial=document.createElement('script');
      initial.setAttribute('src','./assets/js/initial.js');
      document.head.appendChild(initial);
 }
}
</script>
```

while for testing purpose, my js scripts contains,

```
console.log("i'm working");
```

It's linked but console is showing following error:-

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I don't know how does it find console '<' when it clearly don't contain any.

**Edit:-**
Console also shows another warning message:-

```
The script from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/js/initial.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

and when i clicked on the file it loads , it shows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <title>reminder</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
 <body>
  <noscript>
     <strong>We're sorry but reminder doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's actually `public/index.html` not `initial.js`.On opening network tab, i notice that it caches the initial.js , hence it's not updating on reload.

Comment: Please see network tab of your browsers developer tools and check how response for /assets/js/initial.js resource looks like, or whether it even loaded?

Comment: `initial.js` is a static asset that actually belongs in `public/`. For example, if your project directory had `public/js/initial.js`, your script could be imported with `<script src="js/initial.js"></script>`.

Comment: there is no such `initial.js` asset in public/

Answer (score 1):

Do not use relative path for JavaScript src.

Change to absolute path `/assets/js/initial.js`. Remove the dot and keep forward slash.

On a side note, it is a bad practice to add JavaScript files (or StyleSheets) like this. Either already include it in the head, or use an asset bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).